# Does user input get deleted after the completion of a console application in C# or is there a command for it after it successfully runs?

Tags: c#, user-input, private

Just a general question for a chat bot console application I am writing in C#. Does user input get saved or automatically purged after a console application exits or is there a command I should run right before it terminates? I would like to ensure user input remains private and secure. I couldn’t find the answer on here. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

For those asking for more of a detailed explanation of my question, I’m designing a sort of self-help chat bot and user input would be strings which I am using if else statements to filter paired keywords and custom responses. The reason I’m asking about the user input being deleted is because users might reveal personally private information and I wanted to make sure that when being used my application would erase all user input once the application is terminated. I’m thinking of hosting this application as a web based and possibly mobile text application so this question may apply to those platforms as well.

If the user input is erased after the application terminates then that’s perfect and what I want to hear. I’ll have to do more research on cellular and web based platforms though to make sure all user input remains private and is erased after termination.

Comment: Please explain better what is your particular problem so we can help you out.

Comment: of course unless your app does not safe the input to some persistant storage, that data will be lost when that app terminates. Maybe we could help you better if you provided what kind of iinput you're talking about and what your app does with that data.

Comment: When the process ends it frees all memory associated with this process. But you can write a console application to redirect the output to a file stream in addition to the screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone. The fact that a console application erases all user input after running and terminating is exactly what I wanted to hear. I edited my original question to add more context as to why I asked this question. I appreciate your responses!